# Using blogdown with Windows

Tags: blogdown

Everything looks successful with loading `blogdown` and installing Hugo, but when I go to generate a new site in an empty folder, I get the following warning message:

`running command '"C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "." --force -f toml' had status 127`

It's a particularly unhelpful message because it doesn't even turn up answers on google. Any ideas where the problem might be? Everything I am running (R, RStudio, packages) is up to date.

Comment: It is generated from the [`hugo new site`](https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo_new_site/) command. Is your working directory properly set?

Comment: What version or R are you using?